# how to pass special char \ in query string?

Tags: url, restful-url

I want to pass a variable named as \Set in query string. Can anyone please help me how to pass this in query string of url because currently I am getting 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to [URL-encode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) characters which otherwise already have meanings in a URL.

So this:

```
\Set
```

Becomes this:

```
%5CSet
```

Comment: I tried with that also but still I am getting the same error. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: @Sourabh: Without any information about the URL you're using and the error you're getting, I can't really help with that.  No, there's no other way to pass a non-URL-encoded value in a URL other than to, well, URL-encode it.

Comment: Actually I am using Jmeter to get a response data from Rest API, where I have to pass setname as variable in url, but whenever I am sending request to server getting a Response code: 404 and Response message: Not Found. My Url is GET http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/getset/%5CSet01

Comment: @Sourabh: If it's not found then it's not found.  You're going to have to look at the server-side code for that.  The URL is otherwise valid.